# Failed to create virtual interface using iw

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian-stretch, virtual-network-interface

When I tried to create a virtual interface using

```
sudo iw phy `ls /sys/class/ieee80211/` interface add p2p0 type managed
```

it is showing `command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)`. And I tried this too

```
sudo iw phy phy0 interface add p2p0 type managed addr 12:34:56:78:90:12
```

it is giving the same output.

This command is tried on Raspberry Pi running on Raspbian stretch. How can I create a Virtual interface?

Answer (score 1):

If you execute this command:

```
iw list | grep -A 2 'interface combination'
```

You will get an output like the following, if on a Raspberry Pi3:

```
valid interface combinations:
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
       total <= 3, #channels <= 2
```

This means that the maximum allowed managed interfaces is 1. Hence the resource will report busy if trying to set another one as managed.